# Mock state is lost between JUnit test method invocations

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I don't understand why `test1()` fails although it does the same as `test2()`. And the other test method succeeds...

I get NPE in `assertTrue(str.equals("hello"));`

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doAnswer;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

class UnderTest {
    private static UnderTest instance;
    private ToMock toMock;

    public void doSomething() {
        String str = toMock.get();
        assertTrue(str.equals("hello"));
    }

    public static UnderTest getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new UnderTest();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void set(ToMock toMock) {
        this.toMock = toMock;
    }

    public ToMock get() {
        return toMock;
    }
}

public class SomeTest extends TestCase {
    private ToMock toMock;
    private UnderTest underTest;
    private String str;

    public SomeTest() {
        toMock = mock(ToMock.class);

        doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
            public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                str = (String) args[0];
                return null;
            }
        }).when(toMock).set((String) org.mockito.Mockito.any());

        when(toMock.get()).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
            @Override
            public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                return str;
            }
        });

        UnderTest.getInstance().set(toMock);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //      UnderTest.getInstance().set(toMock);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        toMock.set("hello");
        UnderTest.getInstance().doSomething();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        toMock.set("hello");
        UnderTest.getInstance().doSomething();
    }
}
```

The interface below should be placed in an extra file. Otherwise it can't be mocked by **Mockito**.

```
public interface ToMock {
    void set(String str);
    String get();
}
```

But as soon as I uncomment:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    //      UnderTest.getInstance().set(toMock);
}
```

both methods will succeed. I don't see how this instruction affects the `str` field. It looks like `str` is set to `null` between the invocations of `test1()` and `test2()`. But why and where? As far as I know I don't have to call `setUp()` just to keep the current values of some fields. The state of `SomeTest` (`str` included) shouldn't be lost between the test method invocations in JUnit.

How can it be explained?

Comment: Why are you mixing up JUnit versions? `junit.framework.TestCase` and `org.junit.*`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I've just confined it to one - junit.framework.TestCase with the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing JUnit 3 and JUnit 4. Don't. Get rid of the

```
extends TestCase {
```

which presumably makes your test runner use JUnit 3 for running the tests.

JUnit always create a new instance of the test class to run each test method.

In JUnit 3, the runner prepares all instances before executing any of the methods. In your case, execution basically goes like this

1. Instantiate `SomeTest`, instance **A**
2. Invoke constructor on instance **A**
3. Instantiate `ToMock`, instance **B**, bound to instance **A**, and register it in `UnderTest` singleton
4. Instantiate `SomeTest`, instance **C**
5. Invoke constructor on instance **C**
6. Instantiate `ToMock`, instance **D**, bound to instance **C**, and register it in `UnderTest` singleton, **overwriting what was there before**
7. Invoke `test1` on instance **A**
8. Invoke `set` on `ToMock` instance **B**
9. **Invoke `doSomething` on `ToMock` instance D because that's the one stored in `UnderTest` singleton, retrieved through `getInstance`**

That `ToMock` instance **D** hasn't had `set` called on it yet. The corresponding `SomeTest` instance `C`'s `str` field is therefore still `null`.

---

With JUnit 4, we alternate creating an instance with running the corresponding test. In your test case, the `UnderTest` singleton wouldn't be "poluted" with the wrong `ToMock` instance.

Comment: I've set breakpoints in constructor and the both test methods. The control flow is as you've described. But isn't it stupid and counter-intuitive? I mean you normally expect the constructor to be invoked once. I may have used JUnit 4 all the time. I've never thought about the difference between the versions. Unfortunately JUnit 3 is used in the project, so I have to use it. A switch may be possible but not so quickly.

Comment: @ka3ak This is a design decision by JUnit. See Martin Fowler's article about it, [here](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/JunitNewInstance.html). In your case, instead of giving the `ToMock` to your singleton in the constructor, do it in each test or in the `@Before`.

Answer (score 1):

Any updates to setup method (@Before) and @After annotated methods will persist between method calls.

```
 @Before
public void executedBeforeEach() {
....
}
```

The call however will be invoked each time before/after test method is called. If this is not sufficient for you then consider using @BeforeClass annotations.